# Can't access nested Objects JSON in React JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can access JSON objects in the results here

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/user/${userid}`,{
        method:'get',
        headers:{
            "Authorization":`Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`}

    }).then(res=>res.json())
        .then(result=>{
            console.log(result.user.name) //I can access JSON objects in the results here//
            setProfile(result)
        })
        .catch(err=>console.log(err))

}, [])
```

I can access JSON while Changing State but it throws errors like `UserProfile.user` is undefined,`UserProfile.posts.length` is undefined  when rendering JSX. TO access the nested Data I have tried creating more state Variables. It works but the code have become long. I looked for solution in various website but could not find. Any one help me.

```
return (
    <>
        {
            UserProfile?<div style={{maxWidth:'800px',margin:"0px auto"}}>

                    <div style={{
                        display:"flex",
                        justifyContent:'space-around',
                        margin:"18px 0px"
                    }}>
                        <div>
                            <img style={{borderBottom:"1px solid grey",width:"160px",height:"160px",borderRadius:"80px"}} src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1569466896818-335b1bedfcce?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"/>

                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h4>{UserProfile?UserProfile.user.name:"Loading..."}</h4>

                            <div style={{display:"flex",justifyContent:"space-between",width:"100%"}}>
                                <h6>{UserProfile.posts.length} posts &nbsp;</h6>

                                <button onClick={()=>followUser()} className="btn waves-effect waves-light #64b5f6 blue lighten-2" type="button" name="action">Follow</button>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div className="gallery">
                        {
                            UserProfile.posts.map((item)=>{
                                return(
                                    <img className="item" key={item._id} src={item.photo}/>
                                )

                            })

                        }
                    </div>
                </div>:
                <h1>Loading:</h1>

        }
    </>
)

export default Profile
```

Comment: What is your initial state?

Comment: What’s the shape of the object?

Comment: I'd keep all the local variables beginning in lowercase: userProfile, not UserProfile. Remember that uppercase plays a special role in React/JSX. Moreover, I suspect you're using setProfile as setter for userProfile: React guidelines recommends to follow the rule: userProfile - setUserProfile.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code and your inputs, the problem may be because you are trying to access the variables before they are accessible.

As you are making async API call in `useEffect()` it may take some time before you get data. But, as you are accessing the data before you even get it errors like `'UserProfile.user is undefined'`, `'UserProfile.posts.length' is undefined` will occur'

To avoid such errors make sure you add a check as shown below

```
        <>
           {
              UserProfile && 
                <div style={{maxWidth:'800px',margin:"0px auto"}}>
                    <div style={{
                        display:"flex",
                        justifyContent:'space-around',
                        margin:"18px 0px"
                    }}>
                        <div>
                            <img style={{borderBottom:"1px solid grey",width:"160px",height:"160px",borderRadius:"80px"}} src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1569466896818-335b1bedfcce?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"/>
         
                        </div>
                        <div>
/* -----> modify it here*/  <h4>{UserProfile ? UserProfile.user && UserProfile.user.name:"Loading..."}</h4>
         
                            <div style={{display:"flex",justifyContent:"space-between",width:"100%"}}>
/* -----> modify it here*/  <h6>{UserProfile && UserProfile.posts && UserProfile.posts.length} posts &nbsp;</h6>
                 
                            <button onClick={()=>followUser()} className="btn waves-effect waves-light #64b5f6 blue lighten-2" type="button" name="action">Follow</button>
                            
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                       
                        
                        <div className="gallery">
                            {
                              UserProfile.posts.map((item)=>{
                                 return(
                                  <img className="item" key={item._id} src={item.photo}/>
                                 )
                              })
                            }
                        </div>
                </div> 
                :
                <h1>Loading:</h1>
             }
        </>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this. I got rid of this problem by setting initial state to null. Thank You for answering my query.

```
//my initial useState declaration//
const [userProfile,setUserProfile]=useState([])
//Solution//
const [userProfile,setUserProfile]=useState(null)
```

I am new to react so I got into problem.

Comment: Having a very similar problem, describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72810477/second-fetch-in-sequence-of-two-doesnt-seem-to-have-access-to-data-returned-fro). 

Tried your solution, but it didn't work for me. 

What did work was to assign the nested element I wanted ``somewhere.down.the.line`` to another ``var`` (or ``const``) and then referenced that.  This is a kluge at best.  I'd really like to understand why nested objects like this don't seem to work when ``fetch``ed.

Cheers.