# Second fetch in sequence of two doesn't seem to have access to data returned from first fetch

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework, async-await, fetch

I want to query a (django) server for an (RESTful) API schema, then use that schema for subsequent list and CRUD operations as may be defined therein.  I'm using OpenAPI to autogenerate the schema, server-side. Trying to get a client-side API working was taking too long, so I switched to just using `fetch` instead.

The first fetch hits the endpoint that serves the API schema, and works fine.

The problem arises when I try to dereference a string within the returned schema in my second fetch call - this one to retrieve a list of "widget" objects from my server.

I found a way past this by simply assigning the string I needed to another `const` within the same function, then passing this to the second fetch.

This works, but I don't understand why I need to do this to be able to use data from the first call.  I'm able to reference it by `console.log`ging it.  I can see it using the browser's debug console.  But, for whatever reason, a reference to anything in the object returned by the first fetch becomes undefined in the second (or any subsequent?) fetch.

Can someone who understands javascript internals well explain this, or at least point me to something that can explain it?  Thanks!

I've included code below that's been somewhat sanitized.  (I'm obviously not dealing with "widgets".)

```js
// given: a server hosting a "Widget" model, with an OpenAPI
//        RESTful API ...
// we want to retrieve a list of "Widget" objects via the "wigets"
// "list" API endpoint.
async function fetchApi_works() {

  // *** This part works ...
  const api = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/openapi/')
                           .then(r => r.json())
                           .catch(err => {
                                  console.log(err);
                               });
  console.log(api);                      // JSON data for API
  console.log(api.widgets.list.url);     // URL for retrieving list of stores
                                         // Note: NOT undefined

  const server = 'http://localhost:8000';

  // *** This does NOT work ... api.widgets.list.url appears to be undefined.
  const widgets1 = await fetch(server + api.widgets.list.url)
                        .then(r => r.json())
                        .catch(err => {
                            console.log(err.message);  // ** Comes here:  "undefined"
                        });
  
  // *** This works ...
  const widget_api = api.widgets.list.url;  // This seems to be the difference.
   
  const widgets2 = await fetch(server + widget_api)
                        .then(r => r.json())
                        .catch(err => {
                            console.log(err.message);
                        });
  console.log(widgets2);
}

fetchApi_works();
```

Comment: in effect, you say that `api.stores.list.url` works and `api.widgets.list.url` does not work ... if only there were some difference between the two that could explain this mystery

Comment: Thanks Bravo for catching my typo.  Corrected. :)

That wasn't the source of the issue, however.

Comment: would explain it though - what does `console.log((server + widget_api) === (server + api.widgets.list.url))` output - and why do you say ***appears** to be undefined* - it either is or isn't ... what URL is fetched in the developer tools network info tab?

Comment: ``api`` is the object returned by the first fetch.  I'm able to display it (or just some property nested down inside it) using ``console.log``.  However, if I use it (or a nested property in it, like ``api.widgets.list.url``) in another call to ``fetch``, an exception is thrown that I've passed ``undefined``.   If, however, I assign that same property to a ``const`` or ``var`` in the function that's calling ``fetch``, no problem at all.  Works fine. 

I suspect it has something to do with namespace / context / closure.  I'd just like to understand, fully, what's going on.